# FB.api default limit when only returning user ids

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When sending an FB API call for

```
me/friends?fields=id,name&limit=0
```

what is the default limit?

I got 214 friends, but what would happen if someone had 1000 friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would return all 1000 friends in one call.

The default limit is 5000.